# setup/index.sh mongo:not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bash, npm-scripts

Hello I have an nodejs app.In order to setup the app I have a folder called "setup" with the following files:

1. `commands.js`
2. `index.sh`
3. `index.js`

I have also an the following npm script:
`setup:sh ./setup/index.sh`

Here are the contents of `index.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Optikos app database setup on progress";
node "$PWD/setup/index.js";
mongo --p 27019 "$PWD/setup/commands.js";
```

However when I run the script I get the following error:

```
./setup/index.sh: 4: ./setup/index.sh: mongo: not found
```

However mongo is already installed and in my `$PATH`

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here is my `$PATH`:

```
/home/mkcodergr/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/mkcodergr/Documents/GitHub/optikos-app/node_modules/.bin:~/mongo/bin:~/Downloads/ngrok:~/.npm-global/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: is mongo installed? Is it on your $PATH?

Comment: yes it is in my $PATH

Comment: probably not inside your script. try adding this line `echo $PATH` inside your script and run again and see if the printed PATH includes mongo

Comment: it prints my whole PATH as it is including the mongo path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my `~/.profile` file.
I changed the following  lines in the end of the file:

```
PATH="~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"
PATH="~/Downloads/ngrok:$PATH"
PATH="~/mongo/bin:$PATH"
```

to:

```
PATH="$HOME/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$HOME/Downloads/ngrok:$PATH"
PATH="$HOME/mongo/bin:$PATH"
```

And reloaded my profile and it worked

Comment: As for why [here's](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2147) ShellCheck's information about this issue